# How to style Excel cell using Open XML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I have a requirement for export data to excel using open Xml plug in. And I want to style excel head boarder colour. I tried different method to achieve my requirement. Its done, But I couldn't not style particular cells (or columns). I have to add boarder and background to my excel cell.

> My Code as following

```
public ActionResult exxx()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
            WorkbookPart wbp = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
            WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
            fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
            Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();

            //First cell
            SheetData sd = new SheetData();
            Row r1 = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)1u };
            Cell c1 = new Cell();
            c1.DataType = CellValues.String;
            c1.CellValue = new CellValue("some value");
            r1.Append(c1);

            // Second cell
            Cell c2 = new Cell();
            c2.CellReference = "C1";
            c2.DataType = CellValues.String;
            c2.CellValue = new CellValue("other value");

            r1.Append(c2);
            sd.Append(r1);

            //third cell
            Row r2 = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)2u };
            Cell c3 = new Cell();
            c3.DataType = CellValues.String;
            c3.CellValue = new CellValue("some string");
            Cell c4 = new Cell();
            c4.DataType = CellValues.String;
            c4.CellValue = new CellValue("some car");

            r2.Append(c3);
            r2.Append(c4);
            sd.Append(r2);

            ws.Append(sd);
            wsp.Worksheet = ws;
            wsp.Worksheet.Save();
            Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
            sheet.Name = "first sheet";
            sheet.SheetId = 1;
            sheet.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            wb.Append(fv);
            wb.Append(sheets);

            xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
            xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            xl.Close();
            string fileName = "getdata.xlsx";
            Response.Clear();
            byte[] dt = ms.ToArray();

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
            Response.BinaryWrite(dt);
            Response.End();
            return File(dt, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "getdata.xlsx");
        }
```

My expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cdNN.png)

Comment: I need background colour and boarder  for each column header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the style part and reference it by `Cell c1 = new Cell() { StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U };`.

Check

```
public ActionResult CreateExcel()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart wbp = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
    WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart1 = wbp.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rId3");
    GenerateWorkbookStylesPart1Content(workbookStylesPart1);
    WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    Workbook wb = new Workbook();
    FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
    fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
    Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();

    //First cell
    SheetData sd = new SheetData();
    Row r1 = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)1u };
    Cell c1 = new Cell() { StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U };
    c1.DataType = CellValues.String;
    c1.CellValue = new CellValue("some value");
    r1.Append(c1);

    // Second cell
    Cell c2 = new Cell() { StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U };
    c2.CellReference = "C1";
    c2.DataType = CellValues.String;
    c2.CellValue = new CellValue("other value");

    r1.Append(c2);
    sd.Append(r1);

    //third cell
    Row r2 = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)2u };
    Cell c3 = new Cell();
    c3.DataType = CellValues.String;
    c3.CellValue = new CellValue("some string");
    Cell c4 = new Cell();
    c4.DataType = CellValues.String;
    c4.CellValue = new CellValue("some car");

    r2.Append(c3);
    r2.Append(c4);
    sd.Append(r2);

    ws.Append(sd);
    wsp.Worksheet = ws;
    wsp.Worksheet.Save();
    Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
    sheet.Name = "first sheet";
    sheet.SheetId = 1;
    sheet.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
    sheets.Append(sheet);
    wb.Append(fv);
    wb.Append(sheets);

    xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
    xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    xl.Close();
    string fileName = "getdata.xlsx";
    Response.Clear();
    byte[] dt = ms.ToArray();

    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
    //Response.BinaryWrite(dt);
    //Response.End();
    return File(dt, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "getdata.xlsx");
}
private void GenerateWorkbookStylesPart1Content(WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart1)
{
    Stylesheet stylesheet1 = new Stylesheet() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "x14ac x16r2" } };
    stylesheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
    stylesheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");
    stylesheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x16r2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main");

    Fonts fonts1 = new Fonts() { Count = (UInt32Value)2U, KnownFonts = true };

    Font font1 = new Font();
    FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize() { Val = 11D };
    Color color1 = new Color() { Theme = (UInt32Value)1U };
    FontName fontName1 = new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" };
    FontFamilyNumbering fontFamilyNumbering1 = new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 };
    FontScheme fontScheme1 = new FontScheme() { Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor };

    font1.Append(fontSize1);
    font1.Append(color1);
    font1.Append(fontName1);
    font1.Append(fontFamilyNumbering1);
    font1.Append(fontScheme1);

    Font font2 = new Font();
    FontSize fontSize2 = new FontSize() { Val = 11D };
    Color color2 = new Color() { Theme = (UInt32Value)0U };
    FontName fontName2 = new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" };
    FontFamilyNumbering fontFamilyNumbering2 = new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 };
    FontScheme fontScheme2 = new FontScheme() { Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor };

    font2.Append(fontSize2);
    font2.Append(color2);
    font2.Append(fontName2);
    font2.Append(fontFamilyNumbering2);
    font2.Append(fontScheme2);

    fonts1.Append(font1);
    fonts1.Append(font2);

    Fills fills1 = new Fills() { Count = (UInt32Value)3U };

    Fill fill1 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill1 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None };

    fill1.Append(patternFill1);

    Fill fill2 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill2 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 };

    fill2.Append(patternFill2);

    Fill fill3 = new Fill();

    PatternFill patternFill3 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
    ForegroundColor foregroundColor1 = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FF0070C0" };
    BackgroundColor backgroundColor1 = new BackgroundColor() { Indexed = (UInt32Value)64U };

    patternFill3.Append(foregroundColor1);
    patternFill3.Append(backgroundColor1);

    fill3.Append(patternFill3);

    fills1.Append(fill1);
    fills1.Append(fill2);
    fills1.Append(fill3);

    Borders borders1 = new Borders() { Count = (UInt32Value)2U };

    Border border1 = new Border();
    LeftBorder leftBorder1 = new LeftBorder();
    RightBorder rightBorder1 = new RightBorder();
    TopBorder topBorder1 = new TopBorder();
    BottomBorder bottomBorder1 = new BottomBorder();
    DiagonalBorder diagonalBorder1 = new DiagonalBorder();

    border1.Append(leftBorder1);
    border1.Append(rightBorder1);
    border1.Append(topBorder1);
    border1.Append(bottomBorder1);
    border1.Append(diagonalBorder1);

    Border border2 = new Border();

    LeftBorder leftBorder2 = new LeftBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Double };
    Color color3 = new Color() { Auto = true };

    leftBorder2.Append(color3);

    RightBorder rightBorder2 = new RightBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Double };
    Color color4 = new Color() { Auto = true };

    rightBorder2.Append(color4);

    TopBorder topBorder2 = new TopBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Double };
    Color color5 = new Color() { Auto = true };

    topBorder2.Append(color5);

    BottomBorder bottomBorder2 = new BottomBorder() { Style = BorderStyleValues.Double };
    Color color6 = new Color() { Auto = true };

    bottomBorder2.Append(color6);
    DiagonalBorder diagonalBorder2 = new DiagonalBorder();

    border2.Append(leftBorder2);
    border2.Append(rightBorder2);
    border2.Append(topBorder2);
    border2.Append(bottomBorder2);
    border2.Append(diagonalBorder2);

    borders1.Append(border1);
    borders1.Append(border2);

    CellStyleFormats cellStyleFormats1 = new CellStyleFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
    CellFormat cellFormat1 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U };

    cellStyleFormats1.Append(cellFormat1);

    CellFormats cellFormats1 = new CellFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)2U };
    CellFormat cellFormat2 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U };
    CellFormat cellFormat3 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)1U, FillId = (UInt32Value)2U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)1U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyFont = true, ApplyFill = true, ApplyBorder = true };

    cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat2);
    cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat3);

    CellStyles cellStyles1 = new CellStyles() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
    CellStyle cellStyle1 = new CellStyle() { Name = "Normal", FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, BuiltinId = (UInt32Value)0U };

    cellStyles1.Append(cellStyle1);
    DifferentialFormats differentialFormats1 = new DifferentialFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)0U };
    TableStyles tableStyles1 = new TableStyles() { Count = (UInt32Value)0U, DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2", DefaultPivotStyle = "PivotStyleLight16" };

    StylesheetExtensionList stylesheetExtensionList1 = new StylesheetExtensionList();

    StylesheetExtension stylesheetExtension1 = new StylesheetExtension() { Uri = "{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}" };
    stylesheetExtension1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main");
    X14.SlicerStyles slicerStyles1 = new X14.SlicerStyles() { DefaultSlicerStyle = "SlicerStyleLight1" };

    stylesheetExtension1.Append(slicerStyles1);

    StylesheetExtension stylesheetExtension2 = new StylesheetExtension() { Uri = "{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}" };
    stylesheetExtension2.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x15", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main");
    X15.TimelineStyles timelineStyles1 = new X15.TimelineStyles() { DefaultTimelineStyle = "TimeSlicerStyleLight1" };

    stylesheetExtension2.Append(timelineStyles1);

    stylesheetExtensionList1.Append(stylesheetExtension1);
    stylesheetExtensionList1.Append(stylesheetExtension2);

    stylesheet1.Append(fonts1);
    stylesheet1.Append(fills1);
    stylesheet1.Append(borders1);
    stylesheet1.Append(cellStyleFormats1);
    stylesheet1.Append(cellFormats1);
    stylesheet1.Append(cellStyles1);
    stylesheet1.Append(differentialFormats1);
    stylesheet1.Append(tableStyles1);
    stylesheet1.Append(stylesheetExtensionList1);

    workbookStylesPart1.Stylesheet = stylesheet1;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Tao Zhou, How can I create another style index in the same page for border with out fill colour. I couldn't understand your style format. And I just flag your comment . Simply notify you(I will undo)